# What really defines a constant?

Tags: java, constants, wrapper, primitive

```java
public class Constants {

    // This is a constant for sure!
    public static final int NUMBER1 = 42;

    // This is a constant.
    public static final Integer NUMBER2 = 42;

     // Is this really a constant?
    public static final BigInteger NUMBER3 = new BigInteger("42");

}
```

Must a constant necessarily be a primitive [`NUMBER1`] (or a primitive wrapper [`NUMBER2`]), or does `static final` is enough to consider a field as a constant [`NUMBER3`]?

Comment: I'd say a constant is a value that cannot be modified during the execution of your program or the "life" of an instence. But it can be anything, as long as it's not mutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `final Object reference = someObject;`, reference is a constant reference to `someObject`. It will always "point" to that object.

However it does not mean that `someObject` itself is constant.

For example, in `final List list = new ArrayList();`, list is a constant that will always refer to the same list, but you can add/remove to that list.

In your example, both `Integer` and `BigInteger` are immutable so both the reference and the referenced object are constant.

Note however that the JLS has [a precise definition of what constitutes a *constant expression*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), which only includes primitives and String.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the actual definition of *constant* from the language spec and not just the obvious semantics.

$4.12.4. final Variables says the following:

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and
>   initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is
>   called a constant variable

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

The reason that the JLS defines constants in such a way is because it gives some additional optimization potentials (well it seemed like a good idea at that time):

```
class Foo {
    public static final int BAR = 5;
}

// other compilation unit
System.out.println(Foo.BAR); 
// compiler is allowed to generate the following code instead:
System.out.println(5);
```